# ¿Por que no sale el valor de la columna id que corresponde al usuario dentro de la tabla en la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

he estado trabajando en una pagina para hacer cursos de capacitacion por lo cual sera necesario registrar las calificaciones obtenidas por los usuarios despues de realizar los examenes, por ello decidi hacer una tabla diferente para guardar las calificaciones de cada una de las 4 evaluaciones. En este momento me encuentro realizando pruebas para poder guardar el valor del id de los usuarios para poder registrar las calificaciones correctamente. En el codigo acontinuacion estoy intentando guardar el valor del ID obtenido con la consulta pero al parecer hay un error en mi codigo:

```
<?php   
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','capacitacion');
    $consulta = "
        SELECT id
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE usuario = rortGe9
    ";
    $seleccion = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    echo "El Id del usuario que se encuentra conectado es: " . mysqli_num_rows($seleccion);
?>
```

Comment: La función **mysqli_num_rows()** te retorna el número de registros de tu consulta mas no el id.

Comment: Cual es la que debo de usar?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un while para recorrer el resultado de tu query algo asi:

```
<?php   
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','capacitacion');
    $consulta = "
        SELECT id
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE usuario = rortGe9
    ";
    $seleccion = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($seleccion)) {
        echo "El Id del usuario que se encuentra conectado es: " . $row['id'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Te faltó la `i` aquí: `mysql_fetch_array`, debería ser: **`mysqli_fetch_array`**. Y, me parece que busca una sola fila, entonces el `while` no es necesario en ese caso.